# How to connect to wireless TV satellite receiver from Mac OS X

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, video, wifi

How could I connect to my satellite receiver from Mac OS X and be able to watch TV and navigate through channel list? Is there any free software that could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dreambox tv satellite receiver , connect to your network and your mac via wireless
on the mac !dreamX
maybe you have to use VLD video viewer

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you want would probably be the [SlingBox](http://www.slingbox.com/).

It's not possible to do this with just software, unfortunately. Satellite and cable boxes are pretty locked down, so you need a hybrid hardware/software solution like the SlingBox.

Answer (score 0):

Not free and not software, but if you want the best results, you'll need [the EyeTV HD](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/products/EyeTV-HD/product1.en.html) from [Elgato](http://www.elgato.com).